# Encoding MJPEG from webcam in UWP development with C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, uwp, mjpeg

this is my first question in StackOverflow.

How can I encode video being captured from webcam as a MJPEG using C# in UWP enviroment (Visual Studio 2017)?
Perhaps using FFMPEG or DirectShow? Any particular bindings required to use them in UWP?

I've been through these walk-throughs trying to go the official way using MediaCapture:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/basic-photo-video-and-audio-capture-with-mediacapture
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.mediacapture

According to Microsoft though, there is no MJPEG encoder included in MediaEncoder (only decoder): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/supported-codecs

About FFMPEG UWP integration, I found this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/using-ffmpeg-in-windows-applications/#HHYbWAVcM7LhkvYZ.97

But it's geared towards decoding, and I want to *encode*.

Just in case someone is wondering, I want to use MJPEG for Two reasons:
1) less CPU intensive (much less) because it doesn't do inter-frame compression, means my Surface Pro (and other similar computers) will keep quiet without fans running like crazy
2) I need *all* frames (i.e. not one every 30) to be crystal clear because of an algorithm I need to run on each of them after

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Federico

Comment: Check [this sample](https://github.com/AristotelisChantzaras/MjpegStreamer) if it is what you want.